# Find directory pattern

Tags: regex, shell

I am trying to get all the zip files that are present under the directory named "target".
I want to search recursively under a given directory for this file pattern - "*target/*.zip"

This is the command that I have:

```
find . -type f \( -path '*/target/*' -a -name '*.zip' \)
```

This one gives me answers that don't strictly match my criteria.
This one also matches files like "target/foo/bar.zip"
I want to prune these results and only get the zip files that are present directly under the target directory. can someone help me with one?

Comment: Can you look for all directories named target first then look in each for zip files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$ find . -type f ! -path '*/target/*/*.zip' -a -path '*/target/*.zip'
```